# WPF Flow Document: adjust cells height when added in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument with a Table inside. When I create the table directly in XAML and when some cell content is divided into two lines, all cells are automatically fit and the entire row is of equal height.

```
<TableRow Name="TestRow">
                        <TableCell BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                            <Paragraph>1</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                            <Paragraph>This is sentence which is divided into two lines</Paragraph></TableCell>
                        <TableCell BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                            <Paragraph>123</Paragraph></TableCell>
                        <TableCell></TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
```

[image]

But when I want to create the table dynamically in code behind, the cells have different heights.

```
tableProducts.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        TableRow currentRow = tableProducts.RowGroups[0].Rows[1];
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("1")) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 0, 1), BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray }));
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("This is sentence which is divided into two lines")) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 1), BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray }));
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("123")) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 0, 1), BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray }));
```

[image]

I can't find any solution on how to align the cells heights when they are created in code behind. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `new TableCell(new Paragraph(...) { BorderThickness = ... })` to `new TableCell(new Paragraph(...)) { BorderThickness = ... }`

So the reason is `Paragraph` takes not all space from `TableCell`, and its border is inside of cell. But if you try to paint `TableCell`'s border, everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks cdmnk! Solution was so simply.